What are some theories regarding how people replicate negative behaviors they are subjected to?
I have been considering explanations for the idea that people often go on to repeat the negative behaviors they receive. This hypothesis may not hold in generality, which I would be interested to hear about. But in case there are special cases where they do, I was considering:

“template theory”: the idea that even if someone does not like how someone (say, particularly a parent or close family member) treats them, simply to be repeatedly exposed to a behavior acts as a certain form of social learning. In future scenarios, when that person is unhappy about something, they may subconsciously fall back on that behavior simply as an automatic coping mechanism or response to cognitive dissonance. Even if they feel it is wrong, it is more like that’s just the type of behavioral response they know of. It’s like a learned behavioral strategy.
A more complex theory regarding psychodynamics. These theories may be more speculative and more difficult to rigorously test, but it would be worthwhile to attempt to do so. I am considering theories of the subconscious in which for some reason receiving negative treatment leads to a weird yet patterned kind of inner inversion where somehow in order to offload that cognitive dissonance they begin acting that way to other people. My idea is that this is not a sort of cliche idea of “lashing out because they feel bad”, even though that might be a decent approximation of what’s going on sometimes. I’m interested in a very rigorous model of psychological thinking processes - my idea of “internalization” is that when someone is criticized or condemned or feels bad, they are basically incentivized to agree that that thing is bad, to deflate the amount of social rejection heaped on them. This requires them to agree that a certain behavior is bad, which naturally causes them to condemn that behavior in themselves, and by natural extension, in other people when they encounter it. This would be my idea for a more specific account of why people go on to replicate the negative treatment they receive.

I’m curious about a range of specific theories regarding this. Thanks.
